# Command + F suddenly does not work anymore on Mathematica 11.3

Tags: user-interface

I use Mathematica v.11.3 on a MacBook Pro (end of 2013). Starting two days ago the function Find does not work anymore: when I try  <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the menu bar becomes blue for about one second, but nothing happens then. Does somebody have an idea?

I tried to reinstall Mathematica, but that did not solve the problem.

Also, I have another version of Mathematica (10.1.0.0) installed on my Mac, and it has the same problem.

Comment: Can you bring up the Find dialog by choosing Find > Find... from the Edit menu?

Comment: m_goldberg When I do this way, nothing happens, no window pops unfortunately.

Comment: High Performance Mark : Yes the "Command + F" functionality works with Chrome or with the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved the problem:

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "DynamicUpdating" -> True]

Everything is fine now !